# User validation exception with the AWS Lambda service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

While calling Amazon Cognito client's confirm_forgot_password operation,

```
response = cognitoclient.confirm_forgot_password(
    ClientId=client_id,
    Username=username,
    ConfirmationCode=code,
    Password=password
)
```

it throws an **UserLambdaValidationException** error.My Error reads like.

> An error occurred (UserLambdaValidationException) when calling the ConfirmForgotPassword operation: PostConfirmation failed with error Nothing here.

I tried looking into other question related to this and found someone mentioning to allow users to sign in with email address as a username in userpool setup. My cognito user pool already has that configuration.

What exactly is this UserLambdaValidationException?

Comment: any solution you found ?

Comment: You need to create an `IAM` for the `lambda` to access `cognito` resources. I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.LambdaCreatePolicy.html) guide, it uses `Aurora` as an example service but you can just use the same for any other service.

Answer (score -4):

It means Cognito service is having user validation exception with AWS Lambda.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: you might need to look at it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-aliases-settings-option-2